# How to use an item on form from another class C#

Tags: c#

So i have created Windows Form Application and made a library added a reference so that i can use classes from library.

Now i have in a method that is in a class that is in that library it needs to change a pic in PictureBox so how do i get access to a pictureBox that is on form(Form1).

And also it would be nice that the method is able to get in what kind of item he is, for example in picturebox1 or picturebox2 so that it changes the pictureBox that it is called from.

But mainly how to access that pictureBox.

Comment: You should name your controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the class library refer to the application, as otherwise you'd have a cyclic dependency. It's hard to say exactly what you *should* do, but generally speaking class libraries shouldn't be interested in changing aspects of a user interface directly - that's normally a more application-specific requirement.

It's possible that what you really want is an event - the class library would publish an event, and the application would subscribe to it. The class library would then fire the event at the appropriate time, leaving the application code to handle the event by changing the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Your library has a class with a method in it, with needs to get access to a PictureBox in any arbitrary Form-Object, is that right?
Let your method in the library class have a parameter of type PictureBox. Call that method from your form and pass on the PictureBox object you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the reference of the Item like this:

```
void DoWork(ref TextBox t)
{ 
    t.Text="Hi!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if `pictureBox` is private inside the `Form1` class, you can create a property to access it from the outside:

```
public class Form1
{
   public PictureBox Pic 
   { 
       get 
       { 
           return pictureBox; 
       } 
   }
}
```

Then you can access it from an instance with `form.Pic`.

Comment: From the outside - from code which has a reference to the form's assembly... which excludes the class library in this case, due to cyclic dependencies.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I didn't really understand where his code is located from the explanation.